# Providing REST APIs: Apache NiFi vs Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, apache-nifi, api-design

We're currently evaluating some open source tools at our company how to create our REST APIs in the future.
Last candidates are Apache NiFi and Spring. I'm familiar with Spring and it's relatively easy to implement APIs that satisfy our needs.

However, I'm not sure if NiFi is the better tool or even designed to purely be used as API provider.

Generally, our APIs do the following:

1. Parse JSON payload/input parameters (sometimes quite complex XQuery stuff on the payload)
2. Send those infos to Oracle DB functions where main logic resides
3. Parse Oracle output and send appropriate HTTP response

If anyone with NiFi or Spring experience (or both) has some more insights on what's the better alternative here, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Roughly speaking, Apache NiFi is used to automate the flow of data between systems. I think Enterprise Integration Patterns is a good read on what it tries to solve.
Spring is an umbrella of frameworks and does a whole lot of things, including exposing Rest APIs.
Based on your use-case, I would go for the Spring Framework.

Answer (score 1):

NiFi isn't specifically designed for creating RESTful APIs, but there's no reason you couldn't achieve this in NiFi. After all, the use-case you describe is pretty much just moving data; `send data payload -> parse data -> send to oracle -> respond`.

You can build complex HTTP handling logic with the NiFI `HandleHTTPRequest` and `HandleHTTPResponse` processors.

You can easily work with JSON in NiFi; either using the concept of Records with `JsonTreeReader`, or using something like `JoltTransformJSON`.

You can interact with DBs, including Oracle, using the `DBCPConnectionPool` and then run SQL using `PutSQL`, `ExecuteSQL`, `QueryDatabaseTable` (and their corresponding Record varients e.g. `ExecuteSQLRecord`).

You'll also gain some of the benefits of NiFi out of the box, e.g. fault tolerance, clustering, scaling out, visibility, lineage etc.

NiFi is a no-code approach, so it's a vastly different experience to developing a Spring application. You'll need to learn the do's and don't's of NiFi, how to properly structure flows, how to scale, etc. You can also extend NiFi with custom development, but you'd have to learn the NiFi structure and APIs.

Obviously, you could achieve all of this with Spring too; if your needs are very simple (you won't need to scale out, you don't need guarenteed fault tolerance, etc.), or if your API is going to branch into wider use-cases than you described here, it will probably be easier as you already have Spring experience.

There are other considerations; how you version control (NiFi has NiFi Registry), external dependencies (NiFi requires ZooKeeper), overhead (NiFi has it's UI for building flows), deployment (NiFi disks requirements for repositories, OS support, etc.), management/support (are you comfortable supporting NiFi/Registry/ZooKeeper if there are issues), upgrades, etc.

Answer (score 1):

@McLovin,  love the name.

As a long time user of NiFi,  I have NiFi APIs in production with several huge enterprises.  I have also experience with Spring and can appreciate both methods.
However, the number one qualifier for NIFI here, in my opinion, is myself, or whomever I am training in delivery, not having to write any code.   This is amazing!!  I also love the ability to set an inbound port in NiFi to accept anything or allow or deny requests based on my flow logic which I can change at any time.   I can modify the flow while it is live.  I can add more logic while it is live.  I can capture exceptions, send notifications, and build in replay ability with requests.

I would absolutely choose NiFi over Spring to create a scalable API.

Answer (score 0):

I would also go for the spring framework based approach. Nifi is more of an ETL like tool